# How many polarisation states does a spin $s$ particle have in $d$ dimensions?

Tags: quantum-spin, representation-theory, spacetime-dimensions

Consider Wigner's classification of massive particles in $d$ dimensions. One is interested in the irreducible representations of the (double cover of the) little group of the reference momentum $p=(m,\boldsymbol 0)$, to wit, of $\mathrm{Spin}(d-1)$. Let $s$ be the spin (weight) of one such representations $R_s$.

> What is $n_s(d)\equiv\mathrm{dim}\ R_s$?

In other words, how many polarisation states does a spin $s$ particle have? In $d=4$ we know that $n_s(4)=2s+1$. I would like to know how this is generalised to higher $d$.

We have for example the trivial representation, which has $n_0(d)=1$, and the fundamental representation, which has $n_1(d)=d-1$. I would expect that the first non-trivial representation should be somewhere in between; i.e., it should have $1\le n_{1/2}(d)\le d-1$. Is this correct? If the answer to the question above is unknown, I would settle for the simpler question

> What is $n_{1/2}(d)$? (i.e., what is the dimension of the first non-trivial irreducible representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(d-1)$?)

---

<sup>**Important note**: here I am asking about *particles*, not *fields*. Therefore, I am not interested in representations of the Lorentz Group, only on those of the Orthogonal Group. I know that the spinor representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(1,d-1)$ has $2^{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}$ components, but that is not (in principle) relevant to my question. In a sense, I am thinking of QFT à la Weinberg: particles come first, and fields later. At this point, I only care about the former; once I understand them, I will care about the latter.</sup>

Comment: I *believe* that if $s$ is even, we have $n_s(d)=\frac{(d+s-4)!}{(d-3)! s!}(d+2 s-3) $ (and I think I could prove this, but I'm not sure). I also *believe* that if $s$ is odd, we have $n_s(d)=\frac{2 (d+s-7/2)!}{(d-3)! (s-1/2)!}$ (but I have no good proof of that, so it is quite possible this is just wrong). If this is correct, we have $n_{1/2}(d)=2$ for all $d$, but at this point I have no reason to believe this is correct at all.

Comment: On- & off-shell DOF of a massless & massive field with spin $s$ in $D$ spacetime dimensions are listed in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/378850/2451).

Comment: Yes, your integral spin expression comports with the standard textbook case that @Qmechanic displays in his answer.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Unless I misunderstood Qmechanic's answer,  it is about the components of *fields*. Here I am asking about *particles*. They are different objects, and the number of components of the former need not (and usually do not) agree with the number of spin states of the latter.

Comment: His answer is about physical d.o.f. of fields, normally associated to particle states. That's what the logic of his formula follows: the respective little groups SO(d-2) and SO(d-1), respectively. My sense is any decent appendix of a supergravity book should settle the issues you might have. Essentially, supergravitists are the only ones to *apply* all these formulas freely, and the stringency of the matchings involved leaves little room for ambiguity.  Trust me, the coincidence of multiplicities noted above is not a random coincidence.

Comment: FWIW the smallest spinor rep of Spin(2k) has dimension $2^{k -1}$. Their dimension does grow exponentially.  Cf. Slansky's standard compendium/review.  Purely group theoretically, spinor reps are produced by Cliffords.

Comment: Just to check your formula, try it for $d=7$ since the little group representations are those of $SU(4)$ (which is $\sim SO(6)$). Therefore, the smallest irreducible representation would have dimension 4.

Comment: @TwoBs. Sure thing, of course. The fundamental of SU(4) is the spinor of SO(6). Slansky covers the waterfront for us. I didn't want to veer into "respectable" mathematese and send the OP to chapter 20 of Fulton & Harris, is all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give you a few basic facts about of representation theory of $SO(N)$ groups (set $N=d-1$ for the situation at hand; also, we should be talking about the universal cover $Spin(N)$, but to be more general let's pretend that we are working with complex Lie algebra $so(N,\mathbb{C})$ -- the representation theory over $\mathbb{C}$, in which one is interested in this case, is independent of signature, and is equivalent to that of $so(N,\mathbb{C})$). There are two different cases, $N=2n$ and $N=2n+1$. In the former case the Lie algebra of $SO(N)$ is of $D_n$ type and in the latter of $B_n$ type; the representation theory is slightly different in these two cases.

The first thing to know is that $SO(N)$ is reductive for any $N$ -- that is, all its finite dimensional representations decompose as a direct sum of irreducible representations, so you only need to know what are the irreducible representations. The second thing to know is that for $N>3$ ($d>4$) there is no single "spin" which labels the representations of $SO(N)$, but instead you need to specify the *weight*, which is a vector of $n$ numbers (recall $N=2n$ or $N=2n+1$). That is just how the life works, and there is no way around this. In particular, for $N>3$ spinor and vector representations are *not* naturally members of the same family labeled by a single spin, so there is no reason to expect that dimension of spinor representation will be smaller than the dimension of vector representation (and this is in fact false).

These $n$ numbers can be taken to be the so-called Dynkin labels, and we can write them as a list $[\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n]$. The $\lambda_i$ are all independent non-negative integers. To show you the basic idea, let us consider $SO(5)$ and $SO(6)$ with $n=2$ and $n=3$ respectively. For $SO(5)$ the simplest representations, which one usually calls spin-$j$, are $[j,0]$. These are rank-$j$ traceless totally symmetric tensors. The spinor representation is, however, $[0,1]$, so it is not a part of this family. For $SO(6)$ we also have the family $[j,0,0]$ and two chiral spinor representations $[0,1,0]$ (left-handed) and $[0,0,1]$ (right-handed). As you can see, spinors are again not a part of the family. More generally, for $N=2n+1$ the last label is the "spinor label", and for $N=2n$ the last two labels are the "spinor labels".

Now, let me stress that you cannot set $j=\frac{1}{2}$ above, because the labels must be integers. You can in $SO(3)$ because there we have the vector $[\lambda_1]$ and $\lambda_1$ is the spinor label and the traceless-symmetric "spin-$j$" family is $[2j]$, a low-dimensional peculiarity. (There is also a similar
peculiarity in $SO(4)$ where the traceless-symmetric irreps are $[j,j]$.) Furthermore, there are other representations besides those mentioned above (you can set all $\lambda_i$ to whatever you want), but they have more complicated interpretations ($p$-forms, mixed-symmetry tensors, spin-tensors, etc).

Important thing to know is, however, that the Fermi-Bose statistics is determined by the parity of $\lambda_n$ ($N=2n+1$) or $\lambda_n+\lambda_{n-1}$ ($N=2n$). Thus to get a fermionic representation it is crucial to set at least one of spinor labels to a non-zero value.

Finally, let me answer directly your question about the dimensions of representations. Hopefully, it is clear by now that you cannot get away with just one number $s$, and instead you need all the $n$ labels $\lambda_i$. Correspondingly, the answer is quite complicated. (Consult any representation theory text for the formula.) The simple special cases are:

- The irreducible spinor representations are $2^n$ for $N=2n+1$ and $2^{n-1}$ for $N=2n$. In the latter case I am talking about Weyl spinors and a Dirac spinor is a sum of left and right Weyl spinors, hence not irreducible.
- Traceless-symmetric spin-$j$ representation has the dimension $$
  \dim [j,0,\ldots,0] = \frac{\Gamma(j+N-2)(2j+N-2)}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(N-1)} = \frac{(j+N-3)!(2j+N-2)}{j!(N-2)!}.
  $$

Comment: Let me stress that physical massive one-particle states are finite-dimensional representations of $SO(d-1)$ (cf. Weinberg), and hence all of the above applies. There is no special representation theory for "particles". It is the same for particles and fields, its just that fields are representations of $SO(d)$ and particles are representations of $SO(d-1)$ or $SO(d-2)$, depending on the mass.

Comment: Another thing is that the spinors I'm talking about are _the only_ representations which can be reasonably called spin-$\frac{1}{2}$. Namely, these are the only representations which can only have angular momentum $\hbar/2$ in any projection. Any other representation is either scalar, or will allow for larger angular momentum projections.

Comment: I think your first comment should be a bullet in an edit of your fine answer, as it seems to be the OP's sticking point. Also, perhaps, a link to @Qmechanic 's answer, since the mere dimension formulas cannot lie. Throop rules!

Comment: @CosmasZachos, thanks for pointing out the mistake in the formula -- I accidentally put an extra gamma function in the first expression..

Comment: Hi @PeterKravchuk, thank you for your answer! It is taking me some time to fully digest it. If you don't mind, I'd like to ask you some questions: 1) To me, the "spin" $j$ (or $s$) is the eigenvalue of the quadratic Casimir $J_{ij}J_{ij}$, where $J_{ij}$ are the generators of the corresponding representation. In particular, $J^2=j(j+N-2)$. How does this fit into your answer? e.g., why can't it be a half-integer? 2) In terms of Dynkin labels, what is the representation that describes the electron for higher $d$? 3) What do you exactly mean by the "spinor" representation? Is it the Clifford one?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform 1) For $SO(N)$, there exists $n$ independent Casimir operators (quadratic and higher-order), with $n$ as above. All these Casimirs take specific eigenvalues in irreps, and e.g. the quadratic Casimir has a more complicated expression in terms of all $\lambda_i$. For fermionic representations it might very well be non-integral.

Comment: 2) We live in 4d, so I don't know what election is described by. As I said in my comment above, the only irreps that allow only for $|J_{ij}|=1/2$ are the spinor irreps. So perhaps you'd want to think that electron in higher $d$ is in spinor irrep, whose Dynkin labels are explained in the answer. 3) Above I'm talking about _irreducible_ spinor representations, commonly called Weyl spinors. They can be constructed as subirreps of Dirac spinors (in turn constructed using Clifford algebra). In odd $d$ they coincide with Dirac  spinors and in even $d$ they are the chiral half of a Dirac spinor.