# How do I calculate the bosonic/fermionic degrees of freedom from the helicity content?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry, fermions, degrees-of-freedom, bosons

After constructing a physical state and discovering the particle content, **how can one find the fermionic and bosonic degrees of freedom?**

**Eg.**

*Constructing the physical states of an $\mathcal{N} = 2$ short massive vector multiplet, with  $s = \frac{1}{2}$ we get:*

$$\left( -1, 2 \times \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right), 2 \times 0 , 2 \times \frac{1}{2} ,1\right)$$

From this I can see the particle content:

$(-1,0,1) \to 1$ massive vector

$\left( 2\times \left( -\frac{1}{2}\right),0,1 \right) \to 1$ massive Dirac Fermion

$(0) \to 1$ massive real scalar

**How do I calculate the  bosonic and fermionic degrees of freedom based on the helicity content?**

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100995/2451

Comment: That is very helpful but it doesn't say anything about fermionic or bosonic d.o.f. , it only mentions general d.o.f.. Is it the same thing? Or is there a relation?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: The answer depends on spin rather than fermions/bosons (although this is of course related cf. the spin-statistics theorem.)